# Do current 4K Monitors have dual panels in them, or is it just a software/connection term?

Tags: lcd, 4k-resolution

For example take Dell's UP2414Q, many resources online mention two panels coming together side by side to make up the monitor itself, which sounds bad, some even claim color differences.

I'm wondering whether there are really 2 panels in this monitor (or other initial 4k monitors in general) or whether it's the (their) computers that handle 4k monitors as dual monitors/panels.
It could even be both I guess, 2 display streams to handle bandwith issues and 2 panels at the same time, for the hardware manufactorers convenience

I would really like some confirmation regarding the current 4k monitor technology, as I'm going to stay away if there are actually multiple panels coming together to construct a single monitor

Reference: http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/what-hardware-do-you-need-to-run-stuff-at-4k-resolution-on-your-pc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The panel is one panel. The gist of what happened is that it took a while before the electronics used were able to do 4K from one data stream using just one display controller chip, so MST (multi-stream transport) was used so that two chips could be used to drive the physical display.

Ref: YouTube video: [NewEgg ASUS PQ321 4K 31.5" LED LCD IGZO Monitor Overview & Interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cStVRJNbjJw) at about 3:20.

Comment: very useful information, thank you, so there is no point in waiting for better monitors, mst will probably stick around, there are a lot of people believing there are actually 2 seperate lcd panels merging together, I'm wondering whether this could be the case in addition to the information about the mst

Comment: @KaanSoral No, there have never been two panels stuck together to make a 4K display: if they could make the edges of the panels zero width then we would already have displays with almost zero bezel width. Recent 4K monitors use new single controller chips for 4K over DisplayPort 1.2 (might be 1.2a), e.g. (and this isn't a product recommendation from me, just a reference): [ASUS PB287Q 4K Single Stream 60Hz Display](http://www.legitreviews.com/asus-pb287q-28-4k-single-stream-60hz-monitor-review_142719).